# How to change images directory to my resource file

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode4, cocos2d-iphone

I am new to cocos2d and I am trying to learn how to change my images directory to resource file inside my project rather than my desktop. The images only show up if the images are on the desktop instead of inside resource file of my game project. Any help will be appreciated.
The error is something like this
012-08-10 15:30:55.884 again[9753:1be03] cocos2d: Couldn't add image:soundoff.png in CCTextureCache

Comment: Have you checked the box that says copy file to the destination folder if needed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you add files to your project be sure to check "copy files into destination group folder if necessary" option on the add files dialog.  For most things you add to your project you wont want to use the project references option.